# Are the bonuses from the Belt of Physical Perfection and similar items temporary?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm confused about the wording in the description of the [Belt of Physical Perfection](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-of-physical-perfection) and several other items that raise stats.

Do they only raise the stats for the first 24 hours and then they don't work anymore?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Your question's been closed; sorry. But we already have an answer for you! So hopefully that helps you out. If *not*, feel free to edit your question to explain why your question is different/why the other question's answers don't help you, and we can re-open this question.